# Unable to access vm instance via ssh anymore

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to see if there's anything I can do to *re-gain* access to my vm instance via SSH. I had access before, I was creating an ssh tunnel to another server and realized I used the wrong one. I killed ssh via 'pkill sshd' and figured I would be able to regain access after a minute however now I'm unable to at all. I just get connection refused, error 255. Is there any way to send a command to the vm instance to have it restart sshd?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. You might try using your web console to reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console). Alternately, try rebooting the VM, there's a chance SSH will come up without an error if you give it another shot.